# regex101 + further understanding + using OR operation

Tags: regex

Working on this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/yM5zA2/2) using this regex `measInfoId=83888334.*Number(\s=\s|:)K'(?P<vlr_fieldname>\d+)/g`

Could someone explain what the green and red is on the right under match 1 and match2 in the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/yM5zA2/2)?

[image]

This is the data I am working on:

```
beginTime="2015-07-30T11:00:00+12:00",elementType="MSCServer",userLabel="MSC01HAM",measInfoId=83888334,duration="PT3600S",endTime="2015-07-30T12:00:00+12:00",measObjLdn="MSC01HAM/ALL HLR:MSC01HAM/HLR Number:K'447559498104",c84162779=4,c84162780=4
beginTime="2015-07-30T11:00:00+12:00",elementType="MSCServer",userLabel="MSCKPR",measInfoId=83888334,duration="PT3600S",endTime="2015-07-30T12:00:00+12:00",measObjLdn="MSCKPR/ALL HLR:MSCKPR/HLR Number:HLR Number = K'8613261621",c84162779=1,c84162780=1
```

but there is a slight difference before the `K'` and I am trying to do and '|' operation `(\s=\s|:)` to capture this. Am I doing it right?

Comment: If you give an example of what you expect as result, it will help to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.  [206-207]   `:` --> Green color
vlr_fieldname   [209-221]   `447559498104`  --> Red color
```

The match showed in green color are the characters which are captured by the first group where the red color means characters which are captured by the second named capturing group.

`regex101` added this coloring to differentiate between the capturing groups.

`(\s=\s|:)K'(?P<vlr_fieldname>\d+)`

`(\s=\s|:)` This would capture a space  and `=` and the space which follows the equals and match the following `k'` because `k'` is not included inside the capturing group. So matching only occurs on `k'` thus `k'` is in blue color.

`(?P<vlr_fieldname>\d+)` called named capturing group, which captures one or more digits which follows the `k'` and we can refer those chars by specifying the group index `\2` or group name `vlr_fieldname`.

Comment: tks for that. not interested in th k'